# Dynamically generate React component names

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this. How can I convert the code below into something more dynamic and succinct?

```
OneComponent = require ('./OneComponent')
TwoComponent = require ('./TwoComponent')
ThreeComponent = require ('./ThreeComponent')

Example = React.createClass

  render: -> 
    filter = @props.filterState

    if filter is 'something'
      tableCmpt = 
        <div>
          <OneComponent
            tasks={@props.tasks}
          />
        </div>

    if filter is 'somethingElse'
      tableCmpt = 
        <div>
          <TwoComponent
            tasks={@props.tasks}
          />
        </div>

    ##... etc

    return tableCmpt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get Crob's answer to work (though I appreciate the hash table idea), but it led me to find a solution - I just skipped the jsx step and used the compiled js:

```
React.createElement(component, {tasks: this.props.tasks} )
```

So all in all:

```
var Components = {
  'something': require('./Component'),
  'somethingElese': require('./Component2')
};

Example = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var component = Components[this.props.filter];
      React.createElement(component, {tasks: this.props.tasks} )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I've done something like this.

```
var Components = {
  'something': require('./Component'),
  'somethingElese': require('./Component2')
};

Example = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var component = Components[this.props.filter];
      return <div><component tasks={this.props.tasks}/></div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Crob, this doesn't appear to be working for me though. any thoughts? I log out the `component` var and it appears to be grabbing the component fine, but it's not instantiating the component